# Show a theory $\Theta$ is complete.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, decidability, quantifier-elimination

I'm taking a introduction to Logic course and came across the following result:

Let $\Theta$ be a theory over a decidable signature $\Sigma$. Assume $\Theta$ has quantifier elimination and $F_0=\emptyset$ (the set of constant symbols). Show $\Theta$ is complete.

This is presented as a direct consequence of the following proposition (which I have been able to prove):

Let $\Theta$ be a theory over a decidable signature $\Sigma$. Assume the theory has quantifier elimination and that for each $\alpha\in A_\Sigma \cap cL_\Sigma$, either $\Theta \models_\Sigma \alpha$ or $\Theta \models_\Sigma \neg {\alpha}$ ($A_\Sigma$ is the set of Atomic formulas and $cL_\Sigma$ the set of closed formulas). Then, $\Theta$ is complete.

I'm missing some basis on FOL and so, some results are really hard to connect. Maybe it's really obvious but I do want to understand why it is a consequence of the second proposition. Thank you in advance!

**EDIT** 
If there are no constant symbols, then the close formulas must be something like $\forall \psi$, which are not atomic formulas and therefore $A_\Sigma \cap cL_\Sigma = \{ \bot\}$. So the previous would hold. Is this the right path?

Comment: What are $A_\Sigma$ and $cL_\Sigma$?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco set of Atomic formulas and set of closed formulas (respectively). I'm going to add this to the question.

Comment: I am not sure to understand. If the a theory has quantifier elimination and is over a signature without constant symbols, then after quantifier elimination the only atomic formulas are propositional variables and $\bot$ and $\top$. I don't see how this theory can say something interesting. Do I miss something?

Comment: In addition  to the assumption of "no $0$-ary function symbols", is there an assumption of "no $0$-ary predicate symbols"? Without something like that, completness won't follow.

Comment: In addition to the assumption of "no $0$-ary function symbols" (i.e., no constants), is there also an assumption of "no $0$-ary predicate symbols" (i.e., propositional variables)?  Without something like that, completeness won't follow. With this additional assumption, the comment by @Taroccoesbrocco essentially finishes the proof: Any propositional combination of $\top$ and $\bot$ can be reduced to just $\top$ or just $\bot$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass there are no more assumptions... I basically copied what was written in my textbook so there wouldn't be any confusions. It may be a question of notation? The book I'm using often defines things in odd ways...

Comment: @davinci_07 Is it possible that, much earlier in the book, where signatures are defined, predicates are assumed to be $n$-ary with $n\geq1$? In other words, might $0$-ary predicate symbols have been prohibited all along, not just in the present context?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I just checked, it's that!

Comment: @davinci_07. Can you share author/title of the book?

Comment: S@zkutch it's "Decidability of logical theories and their combination" by João Rasga and Cristina Sernadas